# Shapefile output

Tags: python, shapefile

I have code that makes a shapefile but the number of fields is dependent on certain factors.   At the moment I'm testing it on input that I know produces 3 fields so have this code.

```
output = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
for i in range(1,(input.fieldcount+1)):
     fieldname = "field" + str(i)
     output.field(fieldname,'C','40')

for i in range(len(output.item)):
       output.point(input.item[i].x,input.item[i].y)
        graphshp.record(input.field[0],input.field[1],input.field[2])
```

But I would like to change this line:

```
        graphshp.record(input.field[0],input.field[1],input.field[2])
```

So it's not hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the pyshp source](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/source/browse/trunk/shapefile.py#790):

> You can submit either a sequence of field values or keyword arguments
>   of field names and values.

To submit a sequence of field values you'd do:

```
    graphshp.record( *input.field )
```

In case you're interested, arbitrary argument lists are covered in Python's [excellent documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).